# How do I avoid having to clear Messages notifications on multiple devices?

Tags: messages

When I get a new iMessage, I'm happy to see a notification appear on all my devices because I might be using any of them. However once I have actually read the message, I don't want to have to go and clear the notification on all the other devices. I'd like all my devices to automatically recognize that I've read the message and clear the notification for me. Is there any way to achieve that or something similarly time-saving?

Comment: I am looking for this answer, too. Seems my iMac and iPhone sync clearing of messages at least, but they (and other notifications) seem to never clear on my iPad and instead accumulate to epic proportions quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This should just work. Here's what I'd check:

- Are all your devices all up to date?
- Have you restarted all your devices?

I see the issue come up on Apple's Community site with that advice: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252811264

In my experience, my Watch may be last to get a notification so even if I've read it on another device, my watch may still notify me.

Comment: You also need to have them sync'ed

Answer (score -1):

To avoid having to clear messages notifications on multiple devices, you can follow these steps:

Disable Message Notifications on Unused Devices: If you have multiple devices linked to the same messaging account, such as smartphones, tablets, or computers, make sure to disable message notifications on the devices you don't frequently use. This will prevent unnecessary notifications from appearing on those devices.

Use a Single Primary Device: Designate one device as your primary messaging device. This can be the one you use most often or the device that is most convenient for you. By doing so, you can limit the number of devices receiving message notifications, reducing the need to clear notifications on multiple devices.

Enable Notification Sync: Check if your messaging app supports notification syncing across devices. This feature allows you to clear notifications on one device, and the changes will be reflected on other connected devices automatically. Enable this feature if available to ensure a synchronized notification experience.

Adjust Notification Settings: Explore the settings of your messaging app to customize notification preferences. You may be able to specify which types of messages trigger notifications, set priority levels, or choose specific devices to receive notifications. By fine-tuning these settings, you can tailor the notifications to your needs and minimize their occurrence on multiple devices.

Sign Out of Unused Devices: If you have devices you no longer use or wish to receive notifications on, consider signing out of your messaging accounts on those devices. This will ensure that notifications are only delivered to the devices you actively use.

Remember to review the specific settings and options within your messaging app, as they may vary depending on the platform and app you are using.

Comment: There's actually some steps which aren't necessary here, actually, I think the only needed one is "Enable Notification Sync".